# my port 80 is being used by something

Tags: windows-8.1, port-80

Some software is using my port 80 and I don't what it is!

Is there a way to trace it back?

I've been hosting/test different web server but none of them are run at the moment, at least none that i know of!

windows 8.1 -btw sry

Comment: Really hard to answer this question without knowing your OS. What research have you done?

Comment: there sorry about that I'm one of thoes windows user that think the world would go under w/out it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On windows:

Run `cmd` as admin and then use:

```
netstat -tab
```

or

```
netstat -ab -p tcp
```

On Linux:

```
netstat -tap
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply said - the kernel.

Port 80 is HTTP.

Kernel driver http.sys is handling this one - and all applications should basically register their URL's there. THis allow mutiple applications to serve different parts of the URL in parallel.

If you want to stop http.sys, have fun:
http://www.mikeplate.com/2011/11/06/stop-http-sys-from-listening-on-port-80-in-windows/

It would be better you would consider any software trying to own port 80 to be written by people not liking windows or not caring about the operating system features and thus forcing exclusive ownership on a known port.

It is quite trivial to register a URL for http.sys and then using the proper API's to get the requests from the kernel.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13895542/http-sys-implementation
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589588/how-to-register-your-application-into-with-http-sys

Any application not doing it - well, there are good and bad programs, and I don't have to run badly written ones.

The idea behind it is extremely good as multiple applications can then share the port.

Explanations - and screenshots of a management program, source included - can be seen at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/437733/Demystify-http-sys-with-HttpSysManager